# How do I find a trustworthy online Nikon retailer in Canada?

Tags: nikon, online-shopping, canada

I rarely use online shops and I had never shopped cameras online!

Today I just checked Amazon.ca and it just doesn't look right to me, it does not look as good as Amazon.com and Amazon.com also says "currently item can be shipped only within the US"

I only know the [Future Shop](http://www.futureshop.ca)... I've heard good things about [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com)... and [Black's](http://www.blacks.ca) is also listed on Nikon's website as authorized dealer...

Which one is more trustworthy for online shopping?

*PS. I'm planning to buy a camera and some lenses, price difference is not important to me and I don't have time for exchange...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Living in Toronto, I've shopped for camera's and lenses from [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/) and [Adorama](http://www.adorama.com/) and I'd no problem with either one of them.  While shopping from [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/), you will have the option to pay import taxes as part of shipping so you do not have to pay it when the item comes to your door.

I usually go to [PhotoPrice.ca](http://www.photoprice.ca/) and compaire prices from different stores.  I find most of the products from [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/) or [Adorama](http://www.adorama.com/) to be cheaper to buy & ship than stores in Toronto.

If you are looking to buy online at a local store, you can try

- [**Henrys**](http://www.henrys.com)
- **[Vistek](http://www.vistek.ca)**
- **[Aden Camera](http://www.adencamera.com)**
- **[Downtown Camera](http://www.downtowncamera.com)**

They are all reputable stores in Toronto which also allow you to shop online.

If you prefere to buy used / refurbished Nikon products, you might be interested in checking out [nikonpricewatch.com](http://www.nikonpricewatch.com)

Answer (score 3):

### [The Camera Store](https://www.thecamerastore.com)

They're a Calgary based company but they seem to have very [reasonable shipping charges](https://www.thecamerastore.com/customer_support/shipping) within Canada. The reason I suggest them is because I've bought several things there over the past few years and the customer service is outstanding and I've never had a problem with the products. They often have the best prices as well. I had to get my Tripod repaired through them but moved to Kingston while it was away. They shipped it to me and it came quite quickly.

> "Standard sized purchases over $500 are shipped free to most* Canada
>   Express Post destinations."